# Adding WCF reference to a C# web application

Tags: c#, wcf, web-applications, service-reference

I have a WCF project (:53763/WCFTestService.svc) and a web application(:50238/CSharp/test.aspx) in C#. I am trying to call the WCF project method in my web application. I have added the WCF project as a service reference in web application.

in test.aspx.cs file I have a method as follows

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static string GetWCF()
    {
        WCFTestServiceClient client = new WCFTestServiceClient();
        string result = client.XMLData("1122");
        return result;
    }
```

When I run this getting error :

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'TestWCFServiceReference.IWCFTestService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element

.

When I add the WCF project as a service reference in my web application, the web.config file in the web application is not updated automatically. (No code is added by default at the time of adding reference).
Do I need to add anything in the web.config file for making it working?

web.config of WCF project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WCFTestService.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestService.IRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web">          
        </endpoint>
      </service>      
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <!--<behavior>
          --><!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment --><!--
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          --><!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information --><!--
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>-->
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share config of your WCF service ?

Comment: Ok.. I have added the web.config file of my WCF project.

Comment: In your configuration file you have only one endpoint with webHttpBinding that is used for restful address. So you can refer [here](http://sandeepkumar1234.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-test-restful-service.html) to configure and test restful service.

Comment: In your configuration file you have only one endpoint with webHttpBinding that is used for restful address. So you can refer [here](http://sandeepkumar1234.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-test-restful-service.html) to configure and test restful service. or add another endpoint to provide service metadata for SOAP client e.g. 

         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestService.IRestService"       bindingNamespace="">
     </endpoint>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's an error you're going to need to resolve when you reference your WCF project. Look on your information tab (not warning/errors) on Visual Studio when you add the reference and you'll see the errors. I'm guessing it'll have something to do with Newtonsoft.Json - which there are many posts about, such as [Error adding service reference: Type is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542371/error-adding-service-reference-type-is-a-recursive-collection-data-contract-whi)

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file you have only one endpoint with webHttpBinding that is used for restful address. So you can refer [here](http://sandeepkumar1234.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-test-restful-service.html) to configure and test restful service. or add another endpoint to provide service metadata for SOAP client e.g.

```
     <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestService.IRestService"                      bindingNamespace="">
          </endpoint>
```